# Dropdownlist in ASP.net C# and mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table 'TYPE' in this table i have 2 columns as 'SKEY' AND 'CASECODE'.

'SKEY' contains text value and 'CASECODE' contains the corresponding numeric value.

I have bound the values in the column 'SKEY' to a DropdownList control in ASP.net 3.5 C#, What i want is on selection of one item in the DropdownList the corresponding value in the column 'CASECODE' should be displayed.

I have created a datasource for a dropdown list and i want to have DataTextField which is visible to the user to be a value from column SKEY and dropdownlistDataValueField to be a value from column 'casecode' but when i try to do

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="skey" DataValueField="casecode" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="S">Select</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'casecode'.


Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'casecode'.
```

**My .aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form title="orderfrm"  id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="validate()" >
    <div>
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-size: x-large" 
            Text="Order Modify"></asp:Label>

        <br />
        </b>
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
            Text="High Court:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            >
            <asp:ListItem>Panaji</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
            Text="Stmp/Regn.:"></asp:Label>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;


        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="R">Registrer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="S">Stamp</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="Type:"></asp:Label>

        &nbsp;

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="skey" DataValueField="casecode" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="S">Select</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="DropDownList3" ErrorMessage="Select Case Type" 
            InitialValue="S">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT testcase.casetype.skey FROM testcase.casetype">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="No"></asp:Label>

&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter Case No">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="Year:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Enter Year">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Year" 
            ValidationExpression="^\d{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


        <br />
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
            Text="Order Date"></asp:Label>


        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Enter Date">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
            Text="(dd/mm/yyyy)"></asp:Label>

        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Date" 
            ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text="Go" 
            onclick="Button2_Click"/>

        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" AutoFocus="true" Height="200px" Width="500px" ActiveMode="Design" Font-Strikeout="false" />
    <br />



  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" 
  runat="server" > </asp:ScriptManager>


    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Show" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Select" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" onclick="Button4_Click" 
        Text="next page" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to do this with AJAX?

Comment: *corresponding value in the column 'CASECODE' should be displayed*, you mean the database column? or some control on the user interface?

Comment: What columns does the table `testcase.casetype` have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select command of your data source does not include a field named casecode:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT testcase.casetype.skey FROM testcase.casetype">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Probably you want to edit `SelectCommand` to something like this (depending on how your database looks like):

```
SelectCommand="SELECT testcase.casetype, testcase.casetype.skey FROM testcase.casetype"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your DataTextField and DataValueField  -

```
dropdownlist.DataSource = <GetData>();
dropdownlistDataTextField="<SKEY column values>"; 
dropdownlistDataValueField="<CASECODE column values>";
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'casecode'.
                   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

                      Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'casecode'.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting CaseCode and Skey from the database? Why don't you post your code, perhaps that could help.

Comment: I had created Datasource using the wizard available in VisualWebDeveloper2008, should i write code for the same?If so than how?I am a beginner to asp.net please help.

Comment: Does your datasource have properties Casecode and skey? You have to check that. I think your dropdown is not able to find Casecode and skey in the datasource.

Comment: no it doesnt have casecode but it has skey both this are in same table, y is it not taking both the columns from the smae table?do i have to create a seperate datasource for the other column in the same table?

Comment: NO you dont need two datasources. Make sure that your table has both Casecode and skey. The names you provide in your datasource should be the same as what you provide in DataTextField and DataValueField properties

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but [`dropdownlist.SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) would give you the value which is the `casecode` in this case.